# Modify and ZIP file in one statement

Tags: powershell, zip, system.io.compression, compress-archive, c#-ziparchive

PSVersion 5.1.18362.2212

I would like to know if it is possible to read in a set of text files, modify their content and their filenames and store the results directly into a ZIP file?

The following reads text files in and modifies them, storing the change into a *new* file:

```
$xSource = "sourcefile.json"
$xTarget = "targetfile.json"
$replacement = "abc"
(Get-Content $xSource) | Foreach-Object {
  $_.replace('[XX]', $replacement).`
} | Set-Content -path $xTarget
```

Is it possible to modify this to store the target file directly into a ZIP file?

I was hoping something like the following would work, but I am unsure of how I can pass the new filename through to the ZIP? or whether the following works at all?

```
$xSource = "sourcefile.json"
$xTarget = "targetfile.json"
$xTargetZip = "target.zip"
$replacement = "abc"
(Get-Content $xSource) | Foreach-Object {
  $_.replace('[XX]', $replacement).`
} | Compress-Archive -Update -DestinationPath $xTargetZip
```

I get the impression that I would need to store the target files into a temporary folder and then pack them from there ... is there any way of avoiding a temporary folder?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Are you looking to do this only for one file or multiple files? This definitely can't be done without prior writing to a file using `Compress-Archive` but it can be done with .NET Apis

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon multiple source files into a single ZIP file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is cumbersome but you asked for it, this is how you can write entries to a zip file without prior writing the updates of your Jsons to new files, in other words, having the contents of the files **in memory and writing them to a zip entry**.

References for the .NET Docs used here:

- [`File` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) & [`File.Open` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-open(system-string-system-io-filemode))
- [`FileInfo.OpenText` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.opentext?view=net-6.0#system-io-fileinfo-opentext) & [`StreamReader` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0)
- [`ZipArchive` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0) & [`ZipArchive.CreateEntry` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.createentry?view=net-6.0)
- [`StreamWriter` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0)

```bash
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.IO.Compression

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression

try {    
    # be aware, DO NOT use relative paths here!
    $DestinationPath = 'path\to\test.zip'
    $destfs = [File]::Open($DestinationPath, [FileMode]::CreateNew)
    $zip    = [ZipArchive]::new($destfs, [ZipArchiveMode]::Update)

    Get-ChildItem -Path path\to\jsonfolder -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
        # `OpenText` uses UTF8 encoding, normally there shouldn't be any issues here
        # but you can also use `Get-Content` instead to get the file content
        $reader    = $_.OpenText()
        $content   = $reader.ReadToEnd() -replace 'hello', 'world'
        # this is yours to define, this is how each entry should be named
        $entryName = $_.BaseName + '-ToBeDetermined' + $_.Extension
        $zipEntry  = $zip.CreateEntry($entryName)
        $zipStream = $zipEntry.Open()
        $writer    = [StreamWriter]::new($zipStream)
        $writer.Write($content)
        $writer, $reader, $zipStream | ForEach-Object 'Dispose'
    }
}
finally {
    $zip, $destfs | ForEach-Object 'Dispose'
}
```

---

If you're looking to simplify the process demonstrated above, reading a zip archive and replacing the content of zip archive entries, you might find it easier with the [PSCompression Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression) (***Disclaimer:*** *I'm the author of this module*).

This is how the code would look using the module:

```
$zip = New-Item 'path\to\test.zip' -ItemType File
Get-ChildItem -Path path\to\jsonfolder -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
    $entryName = $_.BaseName + '-ToBeDetermined' + $_.Extension
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace 'hello', 'world' |
        New-ZipEntry -Destination $zip.FullName -EntryPath $entryName
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not at all cumbersome, and a few minor adjustments to match my requirements and now it works like a charm! :)